# How can I copy Excel rows, filtering for a value, with Python and openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, filtering, openpyxl, autofilter

I have a gigantic excel workbook with a lot of personal data. Each person has a unique numeric identifier, but has multiple rows of information.

I want to filter all the content through that identifier, and then copy the resulting rows to a template excel workbook and save the results. I'm trying to do this with Python and openpyxl.

I thought that applying an AutoFilter and then copying the results would solve the problem. But it seems that openpyxl can only apply the AutoFilter and [not do the actual filtering?](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/filters.html)

I tried to follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918217/python3-openpyxl-copying-data-from-row-that-contains-certain-value-to-new-sheet), but it won't do anything. I want to filter the number in column D (4).

```
import openpyxl, os
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries

#Intitializes workbooks
print('Opening data file...')
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries("A:AG")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
template = openpyxl.load_workbook('Template.xlsx')
templatews = template.active

#Asks for numeric identifier
print('Done! Now introduce identifier:')
filterNumber = input()

#Does the actual thing
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    if row[3].value == str(filterNumber):
        templatews.append((cell.value for cell in row[min_col-1:max_col]))

#Saves the results
template.save('templatesave.xlsx')
print('All done! Have fun!')
```

Any insight on this will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: corrected column number according to @alexis suggestion, although it has not solved the issue.

SOLVED: it turns out that the IF statement asks for an integer, not a string. Using **int()** solved the problem.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    if row[3].value == int(filterNumber):
        templatews.append((cell.value for cell in row[min_col-1:max_col]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it!
It turns out, that

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    if row[1].value == int(filterNumber):
        templatews.append(cell.value for cell in row[min_col-1:max_col])
```

Asks for an integer and not a string in the IF statement. Using the int() method solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `iter_rows()` method returns a sequence of tuples, so they're indexed from zero: column `D` is at index 3. In other words, try it this way:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    if row[3].value == str(filterNumber):
        ...
```

If it doesn't work, have your script print some of the column's values and take it from there. Maybe this cell's format is not what you expect, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It did not solve it, although I'm sure it was part of the problem. I think that it's not actually appending the rows in the new sheet. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: I solved it! Thanks for the index tip though, that was also part of it.